# ImageView isn't center inside CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an image square image, and my ImageView in my CardView is also square, but it shows me a picture like this:
[image: Picture]

Original picture:

[image: Original]

This is my Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/illness_image"
            android:layout_width="364dp"
            android:layout_height="364dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:cropToPadding="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_engagement"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Engagment"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

EDIT: Sorry, but i don't get it. I can't insert my XML code.

Comment: Show xml file..

Comment: post your cardview and layout file

Comment: @Oliver Weidner, show your `ImageView` property on `xml` or add code of `ImageView` in this question.

Comment: Sorry i had problems to insert it. Now its there.

Comment: Remove this tag `android:cropToPadding="true"` and use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` on `ImageView`.

Comment: @Oliver Weidner, is your issue fixed?

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar no it didn't work

Comment: @OliverWeidner, What is the issue now?

Comment: It was the same output like before.
Check the answer of Nilesh Rathod, he almost got it, but there is still one "piece" of the picture missing. Would be great if you could help us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add **`android:layout_gravity="center"`** in your **ImageView** it will work

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/illness_image"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="364dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/dishu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/illness_engagement"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Engagment"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: It's not working, its shows me the same circumcised picture, but thank you.

Comment: @OliverWeidner change the width of `LinearLayout` your to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: It looks better, but the whole picture isn't there yet.
https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=16331743

Comment: @OliverWeidner what is your expected output?? can u share  it?\

Comment: check my question there i posted my original picture

Comment: @OliverWeidner try with `android:scaleType="centerInside"` in Imageview

Comment: Again same output .. i don't get it whats wrong here

Comment: Same output again

Comment: @OliverWeidner just text try to decrease width of your image view like `android:layout_width="200dp"` i think issue with your image not with the code

Comment: @OliverWeidner, can you show us what output you are getting now after making the above changes?

Comment: There we go now its there! Thank you pretty much!

Comment: Great, We are pleased to help you and happy coding. :)

Comment: Thank you wish you the same! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/illness_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="364dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
       />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/illness_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/illness_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/illness_engagement"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Engagment"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove android:cropToPadding and then try

Answer (score 0):

Put this LOC

```
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

to your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/illness_image"
            android:layout_width="364dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_height="364dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:cropToPadding="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like the following:-

```
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/illness_image"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
/>
```